# how to achieve foreign key concepts in rails using association?(new to rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a trouble in my rails project to achieve foreign key concepts, I had gone through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and few of tutorials and came to know that this can be achieved by **association** and I had tried using the same but yet to succeed.
  Actually I am new to Rails and  I continue running into the same path. Any guidance much appreciated...
 As per my scenario , I  am having two models **User** and **Region**
In **User** model there are three fields  **user_id, user_name,  user_region_id (foreign key)**
In **Region** model => **region_id(primary key), region name**

I want to display In **user_id user_name region_name (using foreign key)** on index page of of **user**
so how an achieve this ??Please help me out
your help will be greatly appreciated
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally you should not prefix your column names with `user_` and `region_`, because they are already present in the table named like that. Removing the prefix you can achieve your desired result using following code in your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to remember association in rails is that the model which has the foreign key should have the `belongs_to` declaration.  So in your setup, since a `Region` has many users, it would make sense to have the foreign key in the users table.

Assuming that the foreign key in the users table is called `region_id`, you should declare the following association in the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

So this works because rails assumes that the foreign key is under a column called `region_id`.  **AND** the primary key is under a column called `id` in the regions table.

On the side of the association, that's when you decide if it's a `has_one` or `has_many`.  Since it has already been decided that it should be `has_many`, it's as easy as just declaring that association in the Region model

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

If you want to keep using `region_id` as the primary key for the regions table, change the association in the user model to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, primary_key: :region_id
end
```

**AND** make sure to declare it in the region model so that doing `region.users` will work

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'region_id'
end
```